# grep single pattern having more than one matches

Tags: grep, awk

I have a file (`X.txt`) with a list of unique entries. I would like to use this file to `grep` from another File `Y.txt` which contain more than one entries for single pattern of `X.txt`.

`X.txt` contains:

```
A.0  
B.0
C.1
D.1
```

`Y.txt` contains:

```
A.0  10
A.0  11
A.1  10
B.0  18
C.1  5
D.1  19
D.1  36
D.2  51
```

Desired Output:

```
A.0  10
A.0  11
B.0  18
C.1  5
D.1  19
D.1  36
```

If they are unique simply using `grep -w -f X.txt Y.txt` works. But could someone help me how to modify `grep` for the desired output or using `awk`.

Comment: `grep -f X.txt Y.txt` should give your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `grep -w` does not pick up the A.0 lines because the file X.txt has trailing spaces on that line (breaking the word boundary requirement of -w). Try the "fixed string patterns" flag, `-F`

```
grep -Ff X.txt Y.txt
```

This also works because the files are sorted:

```
join X.txt Y.txt
```